# Как передать массив из одной функции в другие?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Эта функция заполняет массив случайными числами. Как передать заполненный массив в другие функции, чтобы была возможность его обработки?

```cpp
int* int_random()
{
    int mass1[10];
    int i;
    srand(time(0)); 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         mass1[i] = 1 + rand() % 5;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout <<  mass1[i] << " "; 
    return mass1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, такой массив не должен быть локальным. Возвращать указатель на локальный массив - распространенная, но от этого не менее неприятная, ошибка начинающего. Передавайте готовый массив или создавайте его динамически (только потом надо будет не забыть его удалить) - например,

```
int mass[10];

int* int_random(int * mass, int * mass_size)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(0)); 
    for (i = 0; i < mass_size; i++)
```

или

```
int* int_random()
{
    int * mass1 = new int[10];
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
```

Ну, а передавать потом - просто как указатель, ну и рядом - размер.

Но у вас же С++, так что почему обязательно - массив? Можно воспользоваться, например, `std::array` (если знаете размер заранее), `std::vector`. На самый худой конец - обернуть массив в структуру

```
struct intMassiv { int mass[10]; }
```

которую можно возвращать из функции по значению, или использовать `unique_ptr` с динамически выделенным массивом, чтоб потом не мучиться с удалением.